# compute the expected value of the multiplication of the three Matrices

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

I want to compute the expected value of
$$
E[A^TBA]
$$
where $A$ is a random variable (matrix) from Normal distribution:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}       & a_{12} & a_{13} & \dots & a_{1N} \\
    a_{21}       & a_{22} & a_{23} & \dots & a_{2N} \\
    &&...&& \\
    a_{M1}       & a_{M2} & a_{M3} & \dots & a_{MN}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
a_{ij}\sim N(\mu_A,\sigma_A)
$$
and $B$ is a random variable (matrix $M*M$) from Wishart distribution:
$$
B\sim W(w,\Sigma_B)
$$
Also, $A$ and $B$ are independent and as you may know: 
$$E[B]=w\Sigma_B$$

would you please help me in solving $E[A^TBA]$?

Comment: What does $A \sim N(\mu_A,\Sigma_A)$ mean exactly? (i.i.d. rows? columns?) The following may be helpful for $B$: if $\Sigma_B$ is $p \times p$, you can write $B=X^\top X$ where $X$ is $w \times p$ and has rows drawn i.i.d. from $N(0, \Sigma_B)$.

Comment: sorry, I edited the question it was not clear enough